# MySQL, Select a .ini file

Tags: mysql

I have installed the MySQL server and at the MySQL folder i have multiple configuration .ini files such as:

- **my-huge.ini**
- **my-innodb-heavy-4G.ini**
- **my-large.ini**
- **my-medium.ini**
- **my-small.ini**

As i know i should have **1 my.ini** file i should configure so it suit my server, I have searched for the **my.ini** file and didn't find it so i assume that the MySQL server is configured working with one of the configuration files above, If anyone can tell me please where is the configuration file i can edit and pick my own **.ini** file to be used, Also if there is any good tutorial explaining each of the **.ini** above, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: those are the prebuild example ones, for various sizes of services. pick one, and generally it'd be moved to /etc/my.ini or maybe /etc/mysql/my.ini to become the "real" .ini file. You can trivially `diff` the file to see what the differences are.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Hey Marc, What do you mean when you saying "pick one and generally it'd be moved" can you explain please...

Comment: Hey Venom the Version is: MySQL-5.5.30 Win32.